# Is this PAN IIN lookup Restful API useful for EMV developers?

Tags: financial, emv

Searching for a useful online tool to check certain card ranges for scheme, brand, issuer, country etc parameters; I came across:- 
 https://lookup.binlist.net/,

Sample use case:- 
 https://lookup.binlist.net/411111

Referenced also at:-

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/credit-card-metadata-database

Wondering have coders working on EMV and related FinTech areas come across this resource?  Any feedback on accuracy / usefulness in detecting card types / originating country/acquirer etc., would be appreciated.

FWIW, it did gave reasonably accurate (though not uniformly populated) responses on the live cards in my wallet.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If there is a perceived problem with the question it would be helpful to please outline concerns in a comment.

Comment: It worked for my Credit Cards in my wallet for Turkey.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback @AhmetArslan. Please feel free to upvote if you think the post is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the resource but it's not very detailed for many bin ranges especially for African ones where I come from. But at least it tells you the country where the BIN is registered.

Comment: Thanks @maxuville for the feedback.